# How to dynamically take information out of a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to gather each of the membership_name values, and display it.  I've tried some foreach loops, but they always alert my drupal installation as an invalid foreach() command.

This is print_r($myMemberships);

```
 Array
 (
 [1] => Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [membership_id] => 3
                [contact_id] => 1
                [membership_contact_id] => 1
                [membership_type_id] => 1
                [join_date] => 2011-08-23
                [start_date] => 2011-08-23
                [membership_start_date] => 2011-08-23
                [status_id] => 2
                [is_override] => 1
                [is_test] => 0
                [member_is_test] => 0
                [is_pay_later] => 0
                [member_is_pay_later] => 0
                [membership_name] => Orientation
                [relationship_name] => Volunteer for
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [membership_id] => 4
                [contact_id] => 1
                [membership_contact_id] => 1
                [membership_type_id] => 2
                [join_date] => 2011-08-23
                [start_date] => 2011-08-23
                [membership_start_date] => 2011-08-23
                [status_id] => 2
                [is_override] => 1
                [is_test] => 0
                [member_is_test] => 0
                [is_pay_later] => 0
                [member_is_pay_later] => 0
                [membership_name] => Field Production
                [relationship_name] => Volunteer for
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [membership_id] => 5
                [contact_id] => 1
                [membership_contact_id] => 1
                [membership_type_id] => 3
                [join_date] => 2011-08-23
                [start_date] => 2011-08-23
                [membership_start_date] => 2011-08-23
                [status_id] => 2
                [is_override] => 1
                [is_test] => 0
                [member_is_test] => 0
                [is_pay_later] => 0
                [member_is_pay_later] => 0
                [membership_name] => Graphic Design
                [relationship_name] => Volunteer for
            )

    )

[record_count] => 7
)
```

Moreover, I would like to secure each membership_name as variables to grant permissions to user like:

```
 <?php
      if ($orientation) {

      // execute code

 } else {

      // otherwise execute

 }

 <?php
      if ($fieldproduction) {

      // execute code

 } else {

      // otherwise execute

 }

 // etc... etc...
```

This is what I'm using to call upon it, probably completely wrong:

```
 foreach ( $myMemberships as $myMembership ) {
    foreach ( $myMembership as $value => $final ) {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're getting errors about your `foreach()`, then it would be useful to post them here, along with the way you're calling `foreach()`.

Comment: The array is called through this too: print_r($myMemberships);
`foreach ( $myMemberships as $myMembership ) {
     foreach ( $myMembership as $value => $final ) {
   echo 'hello';
        }
    }`

Comment: `warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: **hello**

<- that's what it called back from my code, but it still alerted me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your array then you need to look for members in `myMemberships[1]`, so your code should be

```
foreach ($myMemberships[1] as $myMembership ) {
    foreach ( $myMembership as $value => $final ) {
        // here you have membership properties
    }
}
```

If your array is dynamic instead you'll have to check for that, so you should do something like this

```
foreach ($myMemberships[1] as $myMembership ) {
    if (is_array($myMembership)) {
        foreach ( $myMembership as $value => $final ) {
            // here you have membership properties
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($myMemberships[1] as $myMembership ) {
     if (is_array($myMembership)) {
      foreach ( $myMembership as $value ) {
          echo $value['membership_name'];
      }
     }
 }`

gives me: 33111222210000OV44112222210000FV55113222210000GV66114222210000SV77115222210000VV88116222210000WV

Comment: @inertialmedia try to print_r $value in your inner loop. Is the foreach warning solved?

Answer (score 2):

It's that `record_count` item at the bottom of the array that's causing a problem. Your outer loop will assign `7` to `$myMemberShip` for the inner loop. You then try to do a foreach on that `7` - since it's not an array, you get the warning.

Comment: is there a way to clean the $myMemberships array to not include that item before passing it through a loop?

Comment: Yes, `del($myMemberships['record_count'])`.